# Ошибка типа данных при их передаче между скриптами Python

Tags: python

у меня такая проблема: передаю из script1 данные в script2, на выходе первого и на входе второго типы отличаются(лог), почему так и как это можно поправить?

Script 1:

```py
class Transcriber:
    
    def __init__(self, wf, model):
        self.wf = wf
        self.model = model
        print('trans1')

        self._transcriber()

    def _transcriber(self):
        rec = KaldiRecognizer(self.model, self.wf.getframerate())
        final_result = ''
        print('trans2')
        
        while True:
            data = self.wf.readframes(4000)
            if len(data) == 0:
                break

            if AcceptWaveform(data):
                result = json.loads(rec.Result())
                final_result += result['text']
        print(type(final_result))
        print('trans3')
        return final_result
```

script2:

```py
print('7')
logging.info('starting transcription...')
result = transcriber.Transcriber(wf, model)
print('trans_result')
print(type(result))
print('7.5')
```

```
log:

7
INFO root:starting transcription...
trans1
trans2
<class 'str'>
trans3
trans_result
<class 'transcriber.Transcriber'>
7.5
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: 1) читать легче; 2) можно копировать; 3) поиск работает. Исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: Код нужно приводить в виде текста, а не картинок. И ошибки. И логи.

Comment: Поправил, спасибо за замечание, первый раз тут.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не можете ничего вернуть из конструктора `__init__`. Вы там вызвали `self._transcriber()`, но результат никуда не дели, он просто пропал. Но и `return self._transcriber()` вы тоже не можете сделать, `__init__` этого не позволяет.

Вы можете в явном виде вызвать эту функцию, создав объект `Transcriber()`. Более точный код напишу, когда у вас будет код текстом. Но примерно так:

```
result = transcriber.Transcriber(wf, model)._transcriber()
```

А из `__init__` вызов `self._transcriber()` уберите, он там бесполезен, если вы никуда результат не собираетесь сохранять.

Вообще, если вам экземпляр класса не нужен, то выкиньте из класса `__init__` и передавайте всё что нужно прямо в вызываемую функцию. А функцию эту вызывайте из класса, без создания экземпляра, и `self.` там тоже тогда не нужен:

```
class Transcriber:
    
    def _transcriber(wf, model):
        rec = KaldiRecognizer(model, wf.getframerate())
        ...

...
result = transcriber.Transcriber._transcriber(wf, model)
```

Comment: Спасибо, понял в чём ошибка, result = transcriber.Transcriber(аргументы)._transcriber() то что нужно. Т.е. если бы не использовался конструктор то я бы смог так вернуть как писал выше дописав return, но тогда бы я не смог передать аргументы в скрипт с классом?

Comment: @ILikeTea Я не совсем понял вопрос. Суть в том, что `__init__` всегда возвращает создаваемый экземпляр класса и это поведение нельзя поменять. Вообще если вам экземпляр класса как таковой не нужен, вы можете вообще выкинуть из класса `__init__` и передавать все нужные аргументы прямо в функцию. Сейчас дополню ответ.

Comment: т.е. если я вызываю этот скрипт единожды, то могу просто без инита описать этот класс передавая сразу в метод аргументы так:

```
class Transcriber:
    def transcribe(wf, model):
        ...
```
и просто вызвать его из другого места так: 

```
result = Transcriber.transcribe(wf, model)
```

Comment: @ILikeTea Да, если вам не нужно несколько экземпляров класса, он у вас всегда один, то вам и не нужно создавать его объекты, можно просто пользоваться методами этого класса как обычными функциями.

Comment: Понял, благодарю.